# jasmine unit test "An error was thrown in afterAll"

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm just unit testing whether the component is created or not. Below is my spec file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpXhrBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { ReleaseListComponent } from './release-list.component';
import { ReleaseService } from '../release.service';

describe('ReleaseListComponent', () => {
  let component: ReleaseListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReleaseListComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, MatTableModule, HttpClientModule ],
      declarations: [ReleaseListComponent],
      providers: [ReleaseService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReleaseListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
```

**My component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ReleaseService } from '../release.service';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'bw-release-list',
  templateUrl: './release-list.component.html'
})
export class ReleaseListComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Release notes';
  displayedColumns = ['title'];
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor( private releaseNotes: ReleaseService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.results);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
}
```

I'm getting `An error was thrown in afterAll`  I'm trying to debug for hours but no luck.

I tried `beforeEach` in both `async` and `sync`, I've also imported all the dependency file into the spec file. still throwing the same error.

please suggest me on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to import`HttpClientTestingModule` but then are using :

`imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule ],`. This should be `HttpClientTestingModule`

Then, launch your test in browser and open your `console`, you could see some additional issues in the browser console, which donot show up when you run only in cmd prompt.

for example, i was having some issue with source map and i had to disable it for my test 
using `ng test --source-map=false`